# iMessage Typing Animation

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I want to make a messaging app like imessage. When you type a message, other user see animating three dot in message bubble. How can do this with react native ?

One idea: view should be listview, rows should be three types (your message, friend's message, animating three dot in bubble), if you type a message, your friend see three dot (add typing bubble to list), then when your friend receives your message delete typing bubble from listview datasource and add message to listview datasource, and render list. is it possible? Or whats your suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

1. You need socket connections to respond quickly, REST API is too slow to respond for quick events.
2. Notify the user every time the other user starts/ends typing.
3. Animate whatever you like.

Comment: I know network part. Im asking how to show typing animation and how to delete animating bubble after message receives.

Comment: Well, this should be basic then.